# App Layout of angular components with AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

[image]

Material navigation items are overlapping on app title with app layout of angular components in the device width 320px, and the space between the navigation items are more than required.
So how can fix these two things with the app layout? Help!

app_component.html

```html
  <material-drawer temporary #drawer="drawer"
                   [attr.end]="true"
                   [attr.overlay]="true">
      <div *deferredContent>
          Here is some drawer content.
      </div>
  </material-drawer>
  <material-content>
      <header class="material-header shadow">
          <div class="material-header-row">
              <span class="material-header-title">My Application</span>
              <div class="material-spacer"></div>
             nav class="material-navigation">
                  <material-button class="material-favorite-button" icon 
                   (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                      <material-icon icon="favorite"></material-icon>
                  </material-button>
            </nav>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
            <material-button class="material-more-button" icon (trigger)="">
                <material-icon icon="more_vert"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            </nav>
          </div>
       </header>
    <div class="app_name">

    </div>
    <div class="controls">
       <h3>Options</h3>

       <material-toggle [(checked)]="end" label="end">
       </material-toggle>

       <material-toggle [(checked)]="overlay" label="overlay">
       </material-toggle>
    </div>
</material-content>
```

app_component.css

```
header{

}

.material-header-row {
  background-color: #212121;
  align-content: center;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

  header {
      width: 100%;
  }
 }
```

Even the app layout is also unresponsive at the media of width 320px and 480px

[image]

Comment: You probably need to show us some of your template code and maybe CSS, if you fiddled around with that. :)

Comment: I have added the codes in the question

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is to remove the material-navigation from the buttons. It isn't needed as material-button already provides the necessary padding. In fact no need to use the nav elements at all for buttons.

That said this did surface an bug. The navigation link margin is double what it should be. 48px instead of 24px. I'll fix that and update the documentation to make this clearer.

Thanks for finding the bug and using angular_components